# Determining title in business card reading

Tags: android, ocr

I am making business card reader App. I am implementing Tesseract OCR for getting text from image. I get all the texts printed on Business Card in format like

Mark Henry(Name)
Asst Professor(Profession)
XYZ University(Employer).

But how to decide which text is User name, which one is User's company and which one is his job title. Is there any algorithm for this or what.

P.S. 
Above sequence can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an ideal problem for natural language processing, where you can train a classifier to presume that anything with 'Professor of', 'Assistant to', etc would more likely be a job description, and text with 'Mark', 'Andrew', etc would most likely be a name. This is fuzzy logic and would be a guess at best.

Example - http://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/classifiers.html

```
>>> train = [
...     ('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'),
...     ('this is an amazing place!', 'pos'),
...     ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'),
...     ('this is my best work.', 'pos'),
...     ("what an awesome view", 'pos'),
...     ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'),
...     ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'),
...     ("I can't deal with this", 'neg'),
...     ('he is my sworn enemy!', 'neg'),
...     ('my boss is horrible.', 'neg')
... ]
>>> test = [
...     ('the beer was good.', 'pos'),
...     ('I do not enjoy my job', 'neg'),
...     ("I ain't feeling dandy today.", 'neg'),
...     ("I feel amazing!", 'pos'),
...     ('Gary is a friend of mine.', 'pos'),
...     ("I can't believe I'm doing this.", 'neg')
... ]
```